# NoSuchAlgorithmException error occurred while build appbundle

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I am trying to build appbundle but got some error. i have located my upload-keystore.jks file inside android/app and key.proporties under android folder.
My key.proporties file looked like

```
storePassword=@@Zakir45
keyPassword=@@Zakir45
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=../app/upload-keystore.jks
```

An the error is

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Failed to read key upload from store "/Users/raza/com.nepromedia.license/license_app/android/app/upload-keystore.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.